# Java's Optional Forces Itself or else I get an error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, option-type, optional-arguments

Why do I get an error if I don't use Optional (the IDE suggested I use Optional) as oppose to just using DemographicEntity demoEntity?

```
@Test
public void testFindDemographicsById() {        
    DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1l); /////Gives Error  
}

@Test
public void testFindDemographicsById() {        
    /////forced to use Optional 
    Optional<DemographicEntity> demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1l); /////No Error
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What does `findById` return?

Comment: If `findById` is declared with `Optional<T>` as return type, you can't assign the result of its invocation to a `DemographicEntity` variable.

Comment: You are tagging a lot of frameworks/techniques, but this comes down to simple logic and basic Java. if you call a method with returntype int, it tends to return an int. If you call a method with returntype Optional<T>, chances are, it will return an Optional.

Comment: This is the standard behavior of spring repositories. The return type of single valued queries is `Optional<T>`. This prevents from getting `NullPointerExcepion` when you have null fields in your database. You should not use `get()` on that in production, the best way is to apply `.orElse(<defaultValueOfT>)`, `.orElseGet(Supplier<T> defaultSupplier)` or `.orElseThrow( Supplier<Throwable> yourCustomThrowableThatYouCatchSomewhere). All those return your entity.

Comment: @ernest_k and et al. Got it. Thank you. That makes sense. I think the obvious intuitive idea/thought flew right pass me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `findById` returns an `Optional`. Use `.get()` in order to get the actual value

```
DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1l).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your demoRepo you must have had declared method

```
Optional<DemographicEntity> findById
```

You can fix in two ways.

First one is to change method in repository to return DemographicEntity:

```
DemographicEntity findById
```

The other and better solution is to call

```
demoRepo.findById(1l).get();
```

Comment: your first solution, if that's all you change, your code won't compile.

Comment: True, you will have to change usages in production code as well(if exists already)

Comment: no. I'm talking about the method itself. If at current it returns an Optional, you'll need to change the code to actually change a DemographicEntity instead.